# How do I properly assert that an exception gets raised in pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, testing, pytest

**Code:**

```
# coding=utf-8
import pytest


def whatever():
    return 9/0

def test_whatever():
    try:
        whatever()
    except ZeroDivisionError as exc:
        pytest.fail(exc, pytrace=True)
```

**Output:**

```
================================ test session starts =================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.3 -- py-1.4.20 -- pytest-2.5.2
plugins: django, cov
collected 1 items 

pytest_test.py F

====================================== FAILURES ======================================
___________________________________ test_whatever ____________________________________

    def test_whatever():
        try:
            whatever()
        except ZeroDivisionError as exc:
>           pytest.fail(exc, pytrace=True)
E           Failed: integer division or modulo by zero

pytest_test.py:12: Failed
============================== 1 failed in 1.16 seconds ==============================
```

How do I make pytest print traceback, so that I would see where in the `whatever` function that an exception was raised?

Answer (score 937, accepted):

[`pytest.raises(Exception)`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=raises#pytest.raises) is what you need.

**Code**

```
import pytest

def test_passes():
    with pytest.raises(Exception) as e_info:
        x = 1 / 0

def test_passes_without_info():
    with pytest.raises(Exception):
        x = 1 / 0

def test_fails():
    with pytest.raises(Exception) as e_info:
        x = 1 / 1

def test_fails_without_info():
    with pytest.raises(Exception):
        x = 1 / 1

# Don't do this. Assertions are caught as exceptions.
def test_passes_but_should_not():
    try:
        x = 1 / 1
        assert False
    except Exception:
        assert True

# Even if the appropriate exception is caught, it is bad style,
# because the test result is less informative
# than it would be with pytest.raises(e)
# (it just says pass or fail.)

def test_passes_but_bad_style():
    try:
        x = 1 / 0
        assert False
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        assert True

def test_fails_but_bad_style():
    try:
        x = 1 / 1
        assert False
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        assert True
```

**Output**

```
============================================================================================= test session starts ==============================================================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.6 -- py-1.4.26 -- pytest-2.6.4
collected 7 items 

test.py ..FF..F

=================================================================================================== FAILURES ===================================================================================================
__________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_fails __________________________________________________________________________________________________

    def test_fails():
        with pytest.raises(Exception) as e_info:
>           x = 1 / 1
E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE

test.py:13: Failed
___________________________________________________________________________________________ test_fails_without_info ____________________________________________________________________________________________

    def test_fails_without_info():
        with pytest.raises(Exception):
>           x = 1 / 1
E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE

test.py:17: Failed
___________________________________________________________________________________________ test_fails_but_bad_style ___________________________________________________________________________________________

    def test_fails_but_bad_style():
        try:
            x = 1 / 1
>           assert False
E           assert False

test.py:43: AssertionError
====================================================================================== 3 failed, 4 passed in 0.02 seconds ======================================================================================
```

Note that `e_info` saves the exception object so you can extract details from it. For example, if you want to check the exception call stack or another nested exception inside.

Comment: It would be good if you could include an example actually querying `e_info`. For developers more familiar with certain other languages, it's not obvious that the scope of `e_info` extends outside of the `with` block.

Comment: This is useful if you are expecting an exception to be raised for your test. It's not very useful if your test may raise an exception and you'd want to handle it with grace.

Comment: For a strict or loose error message check (in addition to checking the exception type) use the `match` keyword argument -- also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56569533/145400

Comment: Personally, I prefer using pytest.fail() than assert == False, I find it more intuitive

Comment: Downvoting because it is missing the essential assert on some part of the `e_info`.

Comment: You can either use the `match` as Dr. Gehrcke mentions or you can do an assertion below the `with` block like this: `assert "Could not find match" in str(e_info.value.detail)`

Answer (score 353):

Do you mean something like this:

```py
def test_raises():
    with pytest.raises(Exception) as exc_info:   
        raise Exception('some info')
    # these asserts are identical; you can use either one   
    assert exc_info.value.args[0] == 'some info'
    assert str(exc_info.value) == 'some info'
```

Comment: `assert excinfo.match(r"^some info$")` works as well

Comment: Since version `3.1` you can use the keyword argument `match` to assert that the
    exception matches a text or regex: `with raises(ValueError, match='must be 0 or None'): raise ValueError("value must be 0 or None")` or `with raises(ValueError, match=r'must be \d+$'): raise ValueError("value must be 42")`

Comment: Important note: If the exception was raised without a message, `execinfo.value.args` will be an empty tuple, meaning trying to do `execinfo.value.args[0]` will raise an exception. Safer to do `message = execinfo.value.args[0] if execinfo.value.args else None; assert message == 'some info'`.

Comment: @ChrisCollett - if you expect an error message to be there, and it throws an exception when it isn't: this seems what I want my test to do. It would mean that the error message is missing when it shouldn't be

Answer (score 256):

pytest constantly evolves and with one of the nice changes in the recent past it is now possible to *simultaneously* test for

- the exception type (strict test)
- the error message (strict or loose check using a regular expression)

Two examples from the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest-raises):

```py
with pytest.raises(ValueError, match='must be 0 or None'):
    raise ValueError('value must be 0 or None')
```

```py
with pytest.raises(ValueError, match=r'must be \d+$'):
    raise ValueError('value must be 42')
```

I have been using that approach in a number of projects and like it very much.

Note:
[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337471/how-to-properly-assert-that-an-exception-gets-raised-in-pytest#comment92250169_23514853) by [ilya-rusin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4863734/ilya-rusin) also suggests aforementioned approach.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is the most up to date and "Pythonic", meaning it is concise, reads well and is easily understood.

Comment: I like this better than `xfail` due to the specifics of the message and we can verify multiple `raises` in one testcase

Comment: my `match` seems to fail if the query is multiple lines. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: @Roelant what is the "query" in your case? When you construct a matching regular expression and provide that as the value to the `match` argument then things will work.

Answer (score 98):

There are two ways to handle these kind of cases in pytest:

- Using `pytest.raises` function
- Using `pytest.mark.xfail` decorator

As the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions) says:

> Using `pytest.raises` is likely to be better for cases where you are testing exceptions your own code is deliberately raising, whereas using `@pytest.mark.xfail` with a check function is probably better for something like documenting unfixed bugs (where the test describes what “should” happen) or bugs in dependencies.

Usage of `pytest.raises`:

```
def whatever():
    return 9/0
def test_whatever():
    with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
        whatever()
```

Usage of `pytest.mark.xfail`:

```
@pytest.mark.xfail(raises=ZeroDivisionError)
def test_whatever():
    whatever()
```

Output of `pytest.raises`:

```
============================= test session starts ============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.10, pytest-3.2.3, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0 -- 
/usr/local/python_2.7_10/bin/python
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /home/user, inifile:
collected 1 item

test_fun.py::test_whatever PASSED


======================== 1 passed in 0.01 seconds =============================
```

Output of `pytest.xfail` marker:

```
============================= test session starts ============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.10, pytest-3.2.3, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0 -- 
/usr/local/python_2.7_10/bin/python
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /home/user, inifile:
collected 1 item

test_fun.py::test_whatever xfail

======================== 1 xfailed in 0.03 seconds=============================
```

Comment: `xfail` is not the solution for the problem here, it just allows the test to fail. Here we'd like to check if a certain exception is raised.

Comment: I have to reiterate @Ctrl-C's comment: pytest.mark.xfail DOES NOT assert that an exception was raised, it simply allows it to be raised. This is not what the title of the question asks.

Comment: As is, this answer is misleading. The documentation paragraph explaining xfail should be moved to the top.

Answer (score 65):

you can try

```
def test_exception():
    with pytest.raises(Exception) as excinfo:   
        function_that_raises_exception()   
    assert str(excinfo.value) == 'some info'
```

Comment: To get the exception message/value as a string in pytest 5.0.0, using `str(excinfo.value)` is required. It also works in pytest 4.x. In pytest 4.x, `str(excinfo)` also works, but does *not* work in pytest 5.0.0.

Answer (score 29):

There are two ways to handle exceptions in `pytest`:

1. Using `pytest.raises` to write assertions about raised exceptions
2. Using `@pytest.mark.xfail`

#### 1. Using `pytest.raises`

From [the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions):

> In order to write assertions about raised exceptions, you can use `pytest.raises` as a context manager

**Examples:**

*Asserting just an exception:*

```py
import pytest


def test_zero_division():
    with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
        1 / 0
```

`with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError)` says that whatever is
in the next block of code should raise a `ZeroDivisionError` exception. If no exception is raised, the test fails. If the test raises a different exception, it fails.

*If you need to have access to the actual exception info:*

```py
import pytest

def f():
    f()

def test_recursion_depth():
    with pytest.raises(RuntimeError) as excinfo:
        f()
    assert "maximum recursion" in str(excinfo.value)
```

`excinfo` is a `ExceptionInfo` instance, which is a wrapper around the actual exception raised. The main attributes of interest are `.type`, `.value` and `.traceback`.

#### 2. Using `@pytest.mark.xfail`

It is also possible to specify a `raises` argument to `pytest.mark.xfail`.

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.xfail(raises=IndexError)
def test_f():
    l = [1, 2, 3]
    l[10]
```

`@pytest.mark.xfail(raises=IndexError)` says that whatever is
in the next block of code should raise an `IndexError` exception. If an `IndexError` is raised, test is marked as `xfailed (x)`. If no exception is raised, the test is marked as `xpassed (X)`. If the test raises a different exception, it fails.

> **Notes:**
>
> - Using `pytest.raises` is likely to be better for cases where you are testing exceptions your own code is deliberately raising, whereas using `@pytest.mark.xfail` with a check function is probably better for something like documenting unfixed bugs or bugs in dependencies.
> - You can pass a `match` keyword parameter to the context-manager (`pytest.raises`) to test that a regular expression matches on the string representation of an exception. ([see more](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions))

Answer (score 8):

Right way is using `pytest.raises` but I found interesting alternative way in comments [here](http://pythontesting.net/framework/pytest/pytest-introduction/) and want to save it for future readers of this question:

```
try:
    thing_that_rasises_typeerror()
    assert False
except TypeError:
    assert True
```

Comment: This is bad style. If the "thing" doesn't raise an error, or raises an unexpected error, you get assert False without any context for a test report or analysis. pytest traceback stops at the assertion and it's not clear what was trying to be tested. Even the original comment mentions there are better ways, but "merely to show how fast it is to get a test written". Why was this "worth saving" without that context?

Answer (score 5):

This solution is what we are using:

```
def test_date_invalidformat():
    """
    Test if input incorrect data will raises ValueError exception
    """
    date = "06/21/2018 00:00:00"
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        app.func(date) #my function to be tested
```

Please refer to pytest, https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-raises

Answer (score 4):

If you want to test for a **specific error type**, use a combination of try, catch and raise:

```
#-- test for TypeError
try:
  myList.append_number("a")
  assert False
except TypeError: pass
except: assert False
```

Answer (score 2):

The top answers submitted here are useful if you are expecting an exception to be raised for your test-case. It's not very useful if your test **may** raise an exception and you'd want to handle it with grace in either scenario.

If you have a test-case that **may** (not will) raise exception, I think this might be a better option.

```
@python.mark.parametrize("request_query, response_code", query_response_dataset)
def test_big_query_submission(request_query, response_code):
    try:
        stats = bigquery.Client().query(request_query)
    except Exception as e:
        assert False, f"Exception raised: {e}"
    assert stats.errors is None
```

This way you are covered to gracefully fail a test instead of crashing a test through a raised exception for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding another "dumb" suggestion as I don't see it in the existing answers. Essentially you can initialise an error variable as `None`, do-the-thing in a try/except block, and then check the class/value of the error variable after that

```
e = None

try:
    blah()
except Exception as exc:
    e = exc

assert e.__class__ == ValueError # or whatever you expect
assert str(e) == "expected message"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove "pytrace=True" ?

```
pytest.fail(exc, pytrace=True) # before
pytest.fail(exc) # after
```

Have you tried to run with '--fulltrace' ?

Answer (score 0):

Better practice will be using a class that inherit unittest.TestCase and running self.assertRaises.

For example:

```
import unittest


def whatever():
    return 9/0


class TestWhatEver(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_whatever():
        with self.assertRaises(ZeroDivisionError):
            whatever()
```

Then you would execute it by running:

```
pytest -vs test_path
```

Comment: Better practice than what? I wouldn't call using unittest syntax instead of pytest syntax "better practice" at all.

Comment: It may not be 'better,' but it's a useful alternative. Because the criterion for an answer is utility, I'm upvoting.

Comment: looks like `pytest` is more popular than `nosex`, but this is how I use pytest.

Answer (score -1):

i just wrote a hook every test gets

the hook :

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item: Item, call: CallInfo):

```
    outcome = yield  # The result after the test is completed
    result = outcome.get_result()

    if result.when == "call":
       if result.failed == True:

       else:
```

i have a function that updates a document with test result and adds the trace by using : result.longrepr.reprcrash.message

i Don't know if this is the best way , but it does answer the question of how to print the traceback using only pytest

@Obviously i have some other code