# Python execution get holds in vnclog command

Tags: python, powershell

Please find the below commands, which i write in power shell

```
vnclog keylog.vdo
vncdo -s 192.168.1.5 move 200 550 click 1
 Start-Sleep -s 2
vncdo -s 192.168.1.5 rcapture b.png 7 75 141 193
Start-Sleep -s 2
```

When i try to run those from Python file test_log.py, Program stays in first line itself.
In my local folder i see keylog.vdo file & it is zero bytes.
Please let me know Where do i miss the steps.

Comment: Can you give examples of input data and code of this function fully? I cant reproduce error or just misunderstood your question.

Comment: Ok. When you trying to check exception raising in pytest you can use `pytest.raises(Exception)` It may be helpful I think: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29855337/3054427