# use type error message in pytest parametrize

Tags: python, pytest

I have a function which raises a TypeError when some conditions are met.

```
def myfunc(..args here...):
    ... 
    raise TypeError('Message')
```

I want to test this message using pytest parametrize.

But, because I am using other arguments also I want to have a setup like this:

```
testdata = [
        (..args here..., 'Message'), # Message is the expected output
    ]

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "..args here..., expected_output", testdata)
    def test_myfunc(
       ..args here..., expected_output):

        obs = myfunc()
        assert obs == expected_output
```

Simple putting the `Message` as the expected output in the parametrize testdata, gives me a failing test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't expect message error as a normal output of `myfunc`. There is a special context manager for this - `pytest.raises`.

[For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23514853/3866610), if you want to expect some error and its message

> ```
> def test_raises():
>     with pytest.raises(Exception) as excinfo:   
>         raise Exception('some info')   
>     assert str(excinfo.value) == 'some info'
> ```

So, in your case, this is going to be something like

```
testdata = [
    (..args here..., 'Message')
]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("..args here..., expected_exception_message", testdata)
    def test_myfunc(..args here..., expected_exception_message):
        with pytest.raises(TypeError) as excinfo: 
            obs = myfunc(..args here...)
        assert str(excinfo.value) == expected_exception_message
```

Answer (score 8):

The following is from [the pytest docs here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/parametrize.html#parametrizing-conditional-raising):

## Parametrizing conditional raising

Use [`pytest.raises()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.raises) with the [`pytest.mark.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest-mark-parametrize-ref) decorator to write parametrized tests in which some tests raise exceptions and others do not.

It may be helpful to use `nullcontext` as a complement to `raises`.

For example:

```py
from contextlib import nullcontext as does_not_raise

import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "example_input,expectation",
    [
        (3, does_not_raise()),
        (2, does_not_raise()),
        (1, does_not_raise()),
        (0, pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError)),
    ],
)
def test_division(example_input, expectation):
    """Test how much I know division."""
    with expectation:
        assert (6 / example_input) is not None
```

In the example above, the first three test cases should run unexceptionally, while the fourth should raise `ZeroDivisionError`.

### But that didn't quite work for me...

The example in the Pytest docs caused me to get the error `AttributeError: __enter__`.

It seems that my Python's `nullcontext` doesn't have an `__enter__` method implemented.  Therefore I had to create my own version like this:

```py
class MyNullContext:
    def __enter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
does_not_raise = MyNullContext()
```

and use that instead of importing the builtin `nullcontext`.  You could throw that in a `conftest.py` file so that it's available for all your tests.