# Pytest error with Dictionary output

Tags: python, unit-testing, dictionary, pytest

I am writing one apache log parsing script which return this output

```
'remote_host': '192.168.0.1', 'apache_status': '403', 'data_transfer': '3985'
```

Now to test this script I am writing unittest using pytest

```
import logparsing_apache
def test_final_report():
    output = logparsing_apache.final_report('192.168.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2017:05:54:36 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 3985 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"')
assert output == "'remote_host': '192.168.0.1', 'apache_status': '403', 'data_transfer': '3985'"
```

While running this script, its failing with this error

```
test_logparsing_apache.py:4: 
logparsing_apache.py:25: in final_report
line_dict = apache_output(line)
line = '1'
def apache_output(line):
    split_line = line.split()
    return {'remote_host': split_line[0],
```

> ```
>           'apache_status': split_line[8],
>             'data_transfer': split_line[9],
>     }
> E       IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

```
 logparsing_apache.py:18: IndexError

 1 failed,  in 0.03 seconds
```

As my script return dictionary how to verify its output using assert?

Script:

```
import sys

def apache_output(line):
    split_line = line.split()
    return {'remote_host': split_line[0],
            'apache_status': split_line[8],
            'data_transfer': split_line[9],
    }


def final_report(logfile):
    for line in logfile:
        line_dict = apache_output(line)
        print(line_dict)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not len(sys.argv) > 1:
        print (__doc__)
        sys.exit(1)
    infile_name = sys.argv[1]
    try:
        infile = open(infile_name, 'r')
    except IOError:
        print ("You must specify a valid file to parse")
        print (__doc__)
        sys.exit(1)
    log_report = final_report(infile)
    print (log_report)
    infile.close()
```

Comment: See https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly assert that an exception gets raised in pytest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337471/how-to-properly-assert-that-an-exception-gets-raised-in-pytest)

Comment: Your error and you question are unrelated

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is because your `final_report` function is expecting a file object, not a string. Because of this, your `final_report` function ends up iterating over each character in the string. What ends up getting passed to `apache_output` is the string "1".

You can fix your current exception by passing a list instead of a string in your test:

```
output = logparsing_apache.final_report(['192.168.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2017:05:54:36 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 3985 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"'])
```

If you prefer, you can also use the `mock` library to create a file-like object instead.

For your comparison, you can assert dictionaries are equal, but you need to actually make it a dictionary instead of a string:

```
assert output == {'remote_host': '192.168.0.1', 'apache_status': '403', 'data_transfer': '3985'}
```

Comment: On a side note, you are probably better off using an existing library for parsing the log lines: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apache-log-parser/1.6.2