# Django how to trigger validation of a class property to raise an exception

Tags: django, python-3.x, pytest

I have this function iam trying to test whether if discount amount is greater than the invoice amount then a validation error should be raised. Iam stuck in actually triggering the exception for it to be raised in the test. See below

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    @property   
    def inv_amount(self):
        amount = Sum(quantity * price)
        return amount

    @property
    def discount_amount(self):
        amount = Sum(discount)
        return amount  

    def validate_amount(self):
        if self.discount_amount > self.inv_amount:
            raise ValidationError("discount amount cannot be greater")

def_test_validate_amount_greater_than_discount():
    with pytest.raises(ValidationError) as e:
       #Trigger the exception
```

Comment: @Patrick Artner I have edited

Comment: @Patrick Artner the point is how would i test rasing an exception if i cant set the properties to a value... ignore the syntax errors

Comment: the point is your code throws other exceptions if you do not fix it. nevermind, i go and let you wait for some one to help

Comment: [how-to-properly-assert-that-an-exception-gets-raised-in-pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337471/how-to-properly-assert-that-an-exception-gets-raised-in-pytest)

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the exception you simply should call `i.validate_amount()` (being `i` an **Invoice object** with wrong values) inside your `with`.

Also, you can use `e` to check if that one is your [expected exception](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions).

Edit (based on the comments of your question):

You can't set a property, but you can set the values `quantity`, `price` and `discount` to make it fail, assuming that those are part of the class `Invoice`

Comment: ...Thanks..let me try