# unittest raise exception python

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, pytest

I have the following to see if a DataFrame is empty or not:

```
def emptyframecheck(data_frame):
if data_frame.empty:
    raise Exception('An empty dataframe was passed.')
```

I would like to unit test this but when I run this:

```
def test_emptyframecheck():
    # Given
    workitem_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(HERE, 'test_csv', 'test.csv'))

    # When
    emptyframecheck(workitem_df)

    # Then
    assertTrue('An empty dataframe was passed' in emptyframecheck.exception)
```

I am getting a global name `assertTrue` is not defined. The `workitem_df` is simply an empty frame I am passing. Is there something I am missing or a better approach?

Comment: Maybe you mean pytest.assertTrue or whatever external module you're using for testing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly assert that an exception gets raised in pytest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337471/how-to-properly-assert-that-an-exception-gets-raised-in-pytest)

Answer (score 1):

This error means what it says: `assertTrue` is not defined. Have you imported `assertTrue`? If you imported the testing module but not the framework, you'll have to do:

```
testing_module.assertTrue()
```

If you want to use 'assertTrue` directly, you should write at the top of the test file the following:

```
from testing_module import assertTrue
```