# How to write a unit test for uncaught exception handler

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception

I have a function to catch *uncaught* exceptions, below. Is there any way to write a unit test that will execute the `uncaught_exception_handler()` function, but exit the test normally?

```
import logging

def config_logger():
    # logger setup here

def init_uncaught_exception_logger(logger):
    '''Setup an exception handler to log uncaught exceptions.

    This is typically called once per main executable.
    This function only exists to provide a logger context to the nested function.

    Args:
        logger (Logger): The logger object to log uncaught exceptions with.
    '''
    def uncaught_exception_handler(*exc_args):
        '''Log uncaught exceptions with logger.

        Args:
            exc_args: exception type, value, and traceback
        '''
        print("Triggered uncaught_exception_handler")
        logger.error("uncaught: {}: {}\n{}".format(*exc_args))

    sys.excepthook = uncaught_exception_handler

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LOGGER = config_logger()
    init_uncaught_exception_logger(LOGGER)
    raise Exception("This is an intentional uncaught exception")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly assert that an exception gets raised in pytest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337471/how-to-properly-assert-that-an-exception-gets-raised-in-pytest)

Comment: @cody: please reread the question? "Uncaught" is the distinguishing factor here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of testing that your function is called for uncaught exceptions, it's probably best to instead test that the `excepthook` is installed, and that the function does the right thing when you call it manually. That gives you pretty good evidence that the `excepthook` will behave properly in real usage. You'll want to move your `uncaught_exception_handler` outside of `init_uncaught_exception_logger` so your tests can access it more easily.

```
assert sys.excepthook is uncaught_exception_handler
with your_preferred_output_capture_mechanism:
    try:
        1/0
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        uncaught_exception_handler(*sys.exc_info())
assert_something_about_captured_output()
```

If you want to actually invoke `excepthook` through an uncaught exception, then you'll need to launch a subprocess and examine its output. The [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) is the way to go for that.

Comment: Thanks @user2357112, for breaking down the problem and my mental barriers.

Answer (score -1):

In order to write assertions about raised exceptions, you can use [`pytest.raises`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-raises) as a context manager like this:

> with raises(expected_exception: Exception[, match][, message])

```
import pytest

def test_which_will_raise_exception():
    with pytest.raises(Exception):
        # Your function to test.
```

Now, this unit test will pass only if any code under pytest.raises context manager will raise an exception provided as a parameter. In this case, it's `Exception`.

Comment: See [sys.excepthook](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html?highlight=sys%20excepthook#sys.excepthook), specifically: "_When an exception is raised and **uncaught**, the interpreter calls sys.excepthook..._". Does `pytest.raises()` catch the exception after `sys.excepthook`?

Comment: @QuantumMechanic If the call comes from tested code inside `pytest.raises` context manager then it should. Give me some time, I'll do some research and tests. If this will work then I'll provide a more detailed example.