# How to patch Python's raise (or return) keyword for the purpose of unit testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

What is the namespace for Python keywords that mock.patch is able to catch?

When someone wants to patch open or print then `mock.patch("builtins.open")` or `mock.patch("mymodule.open")` can be used, but that doesn't works, for example, with `raise`.

If I have `raise somemodule.SomeException` statement then I could easily test if the exception is raised, but how I can assert that actually raise keyword has been invoked. Like (with the help of `pytest` and `pytest-mock`):

```
def test_myfunction_calls_raise(self, mocker):
    mocked = mocker.patch("mymodule.raise")
    mymodule.myfunction()
    mocked.assert_called_once()
```

---

EDIT: I've got [a very nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56841434/11703358) and so mock.patch isn't applicable. Beside that and beside obvious solution - testing the outcome - is there some other meaningful technique to test if Python keyword (`raise`, `return`, ...) has been called in a code?

EDIT 2:
Actual code I want to test (pynput's Listener stop() doesn't work well in Xfce, so I have to raise the exception to stop the Listener thread):

```
import pynput
# ...

def stop(self):
    """Stops listener by raising an exception."""
    try:
        raise pynput.mouse.Listener.StopException
    except pynput.mouse.Listener.StopException:
        return False
```

EDIT 3: The method from above is unittested with the following two test methods:

```
def test_stop_stops_listener(self, mocker):
    """StopException is raised if MagicMock has got StopException attribute."""
    mocked = mocker.patch("pynput.mouse.Listener")
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):  # catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
        base.BaseMouse().stop()
    assert hasattr(mocked, "StopException")

def test_stop_returns_False(self, mocker):
    assert base.BaseMouse().stop() is False
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly assert that an exception gets raised in pytest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337471/how-to-properly-assert-that-an-exception-gets-raised-in-pytest)

Comment: Nope, I emphasized that with "If I have `raise somemodule.SomeException` statement then I could easily test if the exception is raised". This question needs an answer of type "The namespace for raise/return/foo is `xyz`.

Comment: You're mixing up keywords with builtin functions. Reassigning keywords will raise a `SyntaxError` in Python. While you can monkeypatch magic methods called by selected keywords (for example, monkeypatching `__import__` will change the visible behaviour of the `import` keyword), but not the keyword itself.

Comment: I'm not mixing anything, I'm searching for an answer, I want to know is there a parallel technique to test if some Python keyword is called - the usual practice in unit testing for such kind of assertion is to call mock's patch on function/method and count mock calls on it.

Comment: I'm afraid, besides rewriting module code on import (e.g. via import hooks) and adding custom introspection information to bytecode (this is what e.g. `pytest` itself does to the `assert` keyword to print enhanced assertion failures), there's not much you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not patch keywords.  They are part of a Python's syntax.  When the Python interpreter takes a piece of Python code, it parses it and transforms it in several steps into some internal representation ('bytecode').  The bytecode, however, has no longer a direct relation to the original source code - the keywords have 'disappeared'.

In contrast, module and class attributes as well as their accesses from within code will still be found in the bytecode.  Patching is basically the temporary replacement of such attributes.

Or, said differently, you can patch attributes, but keywords are not attributes.

Comment: This is well explained, thank you very much. I edited my question: is there any other meaningful technique, beside mock.patch, that I can use in a unit test to assure a keyword like `raise` or `return` is actually called?

Comment: I have not yet understood why the fact that an exception is raised does not give you all the information you need.  Let me guess a bit: Is it that your code contains several raise statements, and you want to be sure that the right one was executed?

Comment: I edited my question, a raise call is needed by API.