# Assert exception message?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using pytest in a project with a good many custom exceptions.

pytest provides a handy syntax for checking that an exception has been raised, however, I'm not aware of one that asserts that the correct exception message has been raised.

Say I had a `CustomException` that prints "boo!", how could I assert that "boo!" has indeed been printed and not, say, "<unprintable CustomException object>"?

```py
#errors.py
class CustomException(Exception):
    def __str__(self): return "ouch!"
```

```py
#test.py
import pytest, myModule

def test_custom_error(): # SHOULD FAIL
    with pytest.raises(myModule.CustomException):
        raise myModule.CustomException == "boo!"
```

Comment: `a CustomException that prints "boo!"` - do you mean a custom Exception whose string representation is "boo"? e.g. you want to `assert str(exc) == "Boo!"`?

Comment: If you actually want to capture stdout or stderr, then you might want to look at the capsys fixture: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html#accessing-captured-output-from-a-test-function

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23514853/2372812, `excinfo.value` is the actual exeption raised so you can do `assert str(excinfo.value) == "Boo"`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
def failer():
    raise myModule.CustomException()

def test_failer():
    with pytest.raises(myModule.CustomException) as excinfo:
        failer()

    assert str(excinfo.value) == "boo!"
```

Comment: That is indeed what I'm looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: Note: you have to access it outside the `with` block as in this answer. You can't access it after `failer()`

Comment: That's true, and it's because any code directly after `failer()` will never be executed - the exception means it wont' get that far.

Answer (score 9):

You can use match keyword in raises. Try something like

```
with pytest.raises(
        RuntimeError, match=<error string here>
    ):
     pass
```