# How to test a single python file having no functions in it? How to test for multiple inputs and outputs?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to test a Python file but the file doesn't contain any functions and hence returns nothing.

##### example.py

```
x = input()
if int(x):
    print(x)
```

I don't want to make a function like this:

```
def check_x():
    x = input()
    if int(x):
        print(x) or return x
```

or

```
def check_x(x):
    if int(x):
        print(x) or return x
```

How to test a file containing an `input` call, or multiple `input` and `print` statements having no functions that return a value?

I use pytest for testing.

Comment: Kurt Cobain would say... *Smells Like Teen's Homework*. Why don't you want to use a function?

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO I am trying to create a website which test codes of user but I dont want to bound them to create a function and do stuf in that with returning something. So user can directly start without a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using pytest, you can first [monkeypatch](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/monkeypatch.html#) the user `input` and the `print`-ed output, then import the **example** module (or whichever module you need to test), then check that the `print`-ed output matches the expected.

Given the **example** module (**example.py**) and a test file all in a directory named **files**:

```
$ tree files
files
├── example.py
└── test_example.py
```

The test function could look like this:

```
import builtins
import importlib
import io
import sys

import pytest
from pytest import MonkeyPatch

def test_example_123(monkeypatch: MonkeyPatch):
    mocked_input = lambda prompt="": "123"
    mocked_stdout = io.StringIO()

    with monkeypatch.context() as m:
        m.setattr(builtins, "input", mocked_input)
        m.setattr(sys, "stdout", mocked_stdout)

        sys.modules.pop("example", None)
        importlib.import_module(name="example", package="files")

    assert mocked_stdout.getvalue().strip() == "123"
```

```
$ python3.9 -m pytest --no-header -vv files/test_example.py
...
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                    

files/test_example.py::test_example_123 PASSED
```

The [`monkeypatch`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/monkeypatch.html#) fixture can replace the attributes of objects and modules, to something that doesn't depend on any external inputs or on the environment.

In this case, the test patches 2 things:

- The [`builtins.input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function, such that it gets the input string from the test instead of stopping to get user input. The mocked user input is saved in `mocked_input`. If the module calls `input` multiple times, then you can change this from a lambda function to a regular function, that returns different strings based on how many times it was called or base it on the `prompt`.

  ```
  # example.py
  x = input("x")
  y = input("y")
  z = input("z")
  if int(x):
      print(x)

  # Hacky way of relying on mutable default arguments
  # to keep track of how many times mocked_input was called
  def mocked_input(prompt="", return_vals=["3333", "2222", "1111"]):
      return return_vals.pop(-1)

  # Return a fake value based on the prompt
  def mocked_input(prompt=""):
      return {"x": "1111", "y": "2222", "z": "3333"}[prompt]
  ```
- The [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) function, which is the default location where the [`builtins.print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function will print out objects passed to it. The print outs are captured and stored in `mocked_stdout`, which is a [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) instance compatible with `print`. As explained in the docs, multiple `print`'s would result in still 1 string, but separated by `\n`, ex. `'print1\nprint2\nprint3'`. You can just split and use as a list.

The last piece of the puzzle is using [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) to import that **example** module (what you call the "single python file" **example.py**) during runtime and only when the test is actually run.

The code

```
importlib.import_module(name="example", package="files")
```

is similar to doing

```
from files import example
```

The problem with your "single python file" is that, since none of the code is wrapped in functions, *all the code will be immediately run the moment that module is imported*. Furthermore, [Python caches imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296036/does-python-optimize-modules-when-they-are-imported-multiple-times), so the patched `input` and `print` would only take effect when the module is first imported. This is a problem when you need to re-run the module multiple times for multiple tests.

As a workaround, you can `pop`-off the cached `"examples"` module from `sys.modules` before importing

```
sys.modules.pop("example", None)
```

When the module is successfully imported, `mocked_stdout` should now have whatever is supposed to be `print`-ed out to `sys.stdout`. You can then just do a simple assertion check.

To test multiple input and output combinations, use [`pytest.mark.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/parametrize.html) to pass-in different `test_input` and `expected_output`, replacing the hardcoded `"123"` from the previous code.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "test_input, expected_output",
    [
        ("456", "456"),
        ("-999", "-999"),
        ("0", ""),  # Expect int("0") to be 0, so it is False-y
    ],
)
def test_example(monkeypatch: MonkeyPatch, test_input: str, expected_output: str):
    mocked_input = lambda prompt="": test_input
    mocked_stdout = io.StringIO()

    with monkeypatch.context() as m:
        m.setattr(builtins, "input", mocked_input)
        m.setattr(sys, "stdout", mocked_stdout)

        sys.modules.pop("example", None)
        importlib.import_module(name="example", package="files")

    assert mocked_stdout.getvalue().strip() == expected_output
```

```
$ python3.9 -m pytest --no-header -vv files/test_example.py
...
collected 4 items                                                                                                                                   

files/test_example.py::test_example_123 PASSED
files/test_example.py::test_example[456-456] PASSED
files/test_example.py::test_example[-999--999] PASSED
files/test_example.py::test_example[0-] PASSED
```

Lastly, for cases like `"4.56"` where you expect an `ValueError`, it's more useful to just [test that an Exception was raised](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23337471/2745495) rather than checking the `print`-ed output.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "test_input",
    [
        "9.99",
        "not an int",
    ],
)
def test_example_errors(monkeypatch: MonkeyPatch, test_input: str):
    mocked_input = lambda prompt="": test_input

    with monkeypatch.context() as m:
        m.setattr(builtins, "input", mocked_input)

        sys.modules.pop("example", None)
        with pytest.raises(ValueError) as exc:
            importlib.import_module(name="example", package="files")

    assert str(exc.value) == f"invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{test_input}'"
```

```
$ python3.9 -m pytest --no-header -vv files/test_example.py
...
collected 6 items                                                                                                                                   

files/test_example.py::test_example_123 PASSED
files/test_example.py::test_example[123-123] PASSED
files/test_example.py::test_example[-999--999] PASSED
files/test_example.py::test_example[0-] PASSED
files/test_example.py::test_example_errors[9.99] PASSED
files/test_example.py::test_example_errors[not an int] PASSED
```

Comment: How do I get JSON response per each test case. Ex `{"test_case_1": {"input": input, "your_output": output, "expected_output": expected_output, "result": pass or fail}, "test_case_2": .........so on}`

Comment: @shraysalvi That's a completely new problem, so please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). See [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266767/2745495). You can try checking https://pypi.org/project/pytest-json-report/.

Comment: I already tried it but it gives me the general information about the test I also tried to change `jsonmetadata` but maybe I am somewhere wrong.

Comment: Ok I got it `pytest -s --json-report --json-report-file=report.json --log-cli-level=INFO` is used to get the json result with collectors. also, can add custom `jsonmetadeta`.

Comment: How do I test this with my `check.py` file, As you give me the solution with pre-defined `expected_output` as a string now how do I test the user's code with my `check.py` file using the same inputs that we provide in test file. For example `check.py` contain solution code now I want to compare solution code with users code but with the same input for both files. (mock_input for both files solution and user's code). suppose `check.py` is also present in our tree files in the files directory.