# Pytest execution result in json format?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I am working on pytest and want result in json format, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73354667/how-to-test-a-single-python-file-having-no-functions-in-it-how-to-test-for-mult) problem.

There is single file which is tested using monkeypatch for custom inputs now I need result for each test cases. I know we can use `pytest test_example.py -v --junitxml="result.xml"` for the result in xml format but I want result in json format.

```
# example.py
x = input("x")
y = input("y")
z = input("z")
if int(x):
    print(x)
```

above is the file which is going to be tested and

```
# test_example.py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "test_input, expected_output",
    [
        ("456", "456"),
        ("-999", "-999"),
        ("0", ""),  # Expect int("0") to be 0, so it is False-y
        ("0.9", "0")
    ],
)
def test_example(monkeypatch: MonkeyPatch, test_input: str, expected_output: str):
    mocked_input = lambda prompt="": test_input
    mocked_stdout = io.StringIO()

    with monkeypatch.context() as m:
        m.setattr(builtins, "input", mocked_input)
        m.setattr(sys, "stdout", mocked_stdout)

        sys.modules.pop("example", None)
        importlib.import_module(name="example", package="files")

    assert mocked_stdout.getvalue().strip() == expected_output
```

this is a testing file  an I use `pytest test_example.py -v --junitxml="result.xml"` which gives me result like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="pytest" errors="0" failures="1" skipped="0" tests="4" time="0.397" timestamp="2022-08-20T23:07:01.073263" hostname="HP">
        <testcase classname="test_example" name="test_example[456-456]" time="0.005" />
        <testcase classname="test_example" name="test_example[-999--999]" time="0.006" />
        <testcase classname="test_example" name="test_example[0-]" time="0.005" />
        <testcase classname="test_example" name="test_example[0.9-0]" time="0.007">
            <failure message="ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.9'">monkeypatch = &lt;_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x000001962E6322E0&gt;, test_input = '0.9', expected_output = '0'

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "test_input, expected_output",
        [
            ("456", "456"),
            ("-999", "-999"),
            ("0", ""),  # Expect int("0") to be 0, so it is False-y
            ("0.9", "0")
        ],
    )
    
    def test_example(monkeypatch: MonkeyPatch, test_input: str, expected_output: str):
        mocked_input = lambda prompt="": test_input
        mocked_stdout = io.StringIO()
    
        with monkeypatch.context() as m:
            m.setattr(builtins, "input", mocked_input)
            m.setattr(sys, "stdout", mocked_stdout)
    
            sys.modules.pop("example", None)
&gt;           importlib.import_module(name="example", package="files")

test_example.py:27: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;:1030: in _gcd_import
    ???
&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;:1007: in _find_and_load
    ???
&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;:986: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;:680: in _load_unlocked
    ???
&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap_external&gt;:850: in exec_module
    ???
&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;:228: in _call_with_frames_removed
    ???
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

    x = input("x")
    y = input("y")
    z = input("z")
&gt;   if int(x):
E   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.9'

example.py:4: ValueError</failure>
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

How do we get info in json format like this one

```
{"name": "test_example[456-456]", "time": "0.005", "result": "pass", "inputs": "456", "user_output": "456", "expected_output": "456", "failure": "reason"}
{"name": "test_example[-999--999]", "time": "0.006", "result": "pass", "inputs": "-999", "user_output": "-999", "expected_output": "-999", "failure": "reason"}
:
:
{"name": "some_test", "time": "some_time", "result": "pass or fail", "inputs": "custom-inputs", "user_output": "user-output", "expected-output": "custom-outputs", "failure": "reason"}
```

Is there any module that can do this type of stuff, I already use https://pypi.org/project/pytest-json-report/ but didn't work.

Comment: Parse `junit.xml` with `lxml`, extract the data, dump to JSON.