# Unit test failure due to second positional argument. Simple math result comparison?

Tags: python, error-handling, typeerror, python-unittest

I am creating unit tests by using the unittest module, and simply asserting Equal a result that is correct when calculating the Fibonacci sequence. Below is the working code- the 5th number is 2+3 = 5.

```
    num1 = 0
    num2 = 1
    find = 2
    fib_num = 0

    while find <= N:
        fib_num = num1 + num2
        num1 = num2
        num2 = fib_num
        find = find + 1
    return(fib_num)


print(fibFind(5))
```

This is mu Unittest

```
from fibfind import fibFind


class TestFibonnaciResult(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_number(self):
        self.assertEqual(fibFind(5)== 5),
        self.assertEqual(fibFind(6)==8),
        self.assertEqual(fibFind(7)== 13)
        5, 8, 13

    def test_input_type(self):
        self.assertTrue(fibFind("some-string") == error)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

In the terminal however, I get this?

```
$ python -m unittest test_fibFind.py
EE
======================================================================
ERROR: test_input_type (test_fibFind.TestFibonnaciResult)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\dev\repos\testing_python\test_fibFind.py", line 14, in test_input_type
    self.assertTrue(fibFind("some-string") == error)
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\dev\repos\testing_python\fibfind.py", line 7, in fibFind
    while find <= N:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

======================================================================
ERROR: test_number (test_fibFind.TestFibonnaciResult)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\dev\repos\testing_python\test_fibFind.py", line 8, in test_number
    self.assertEqual(fibFind(5)== 5),
TypeError: assertEqual() missing 1 required positional argument: 'second'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=2)
5
```

The second test is wanting to make sure only an integer is parsed through but clearly is having issues with the comparator <=

Any help here before I move onto pytest would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly assert that an exception gets raised in pytest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337471/how-to-properly-assert-that-an-exception-gets-raised-in-pytest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other answers are mostly correct, but none touches on the other test that expects an exception to be raised.
`unittest` `assert...` methods have very specific signatures, which you should check before using. In the first test, you basicly did the following:

```
self.assertTrue(True)
```

Doesn't make much sense, right? Instead, you should pass 2 objects as a `first` and `second` arguments, and let unittest handle their comparison.

```
self.assertEqual(fibFind(5), 5)
```

Similiarly, with a bad input test you can't simply call a function with bad arguments and compare to undefined `error`.
There exists `assertRaises` method exactly for that purpose. It accepts an exception type, callable and arguments that will be passed to the callable. Which means you should call it like that:

```
self.assertRaises(TypeError, fibFind, "some-string")
```

All in all, your test class should look like that:

```
class TestFibonnaciResult(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_number(self):
        self.assertEqual(fibFind(5), 5)
        self.assertEqual(fibFind(6), 8)
        self.assertEqual(fibFind(7), 13)

    def test_input_type(self):
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, fibFind, "some-string")
```

Output:

```
5
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.024s

OK
```

Comment: Thanks so much @matszwecja- that is much clearer now, I find the documentations difficult to navigate- your answer is clear and concise.

Answer (score 1):

Python-unittest offers you two options to do what you're trying to achieve.

If you want to write a boolean expression to be compared, you can use the methods `assertTrue` or `assertFalse` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertTrue)).

```py
class TestFibonnaciResult(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_number(self):
        self.assertTrue(fibFind(5)== 5),
        self.assertTrue(fibFind(6)==8),
        self.assertTrue(fibFind(7)== 13)
```

You can also use `assertEqual`, which takes 2 parameters, `first` and `second`, and compares them ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual)).

```py
class TestFibonnaciResult(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_number(self):
        self.assertEqual(fibFind(5),5),
        self.assertEqual(fibFind(6),8),
        self.assertEqual(fibFind(7),13)
```

Answer (score 0):

assertEqual requires 2 arguments, You're only giving it one argument, because your expression evalutes to a True or False value. Try this instead:

```
def test_number(self):
    self.assertEqual(fibFind(5), 5),
    self.assertEqual(fibFind(6), 8),
    self.assertEqual(fibFind(7), 13)
```

Answer (score -2):

In mu Unittest
line 8, 9, 10
assertEqual takes two arguments not one
You also cannot compare an int and a string